# How to use ant design in gatsby (gastbyjs)

Tags: ant, gatsby, gatsby-plugin

I am having problem declaring and using components of antd library specifically as follows:
it seems plugin: `gatsby-plugin-antd` is too old
Example package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@paljs/icons": "1.0.5",
    "@paljs/ui": "1.1.1",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "antd": "^4.4.1",
    "gatsby": "3.12.0",
    "gatsby-image": "3.11.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-antd": "^2.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-layout": "2.12.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "3.12.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "4.12.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "3.12.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "4.12.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-typescript": "3.12.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "3.12.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "3.12.0",
    "http-server": "^13.0.1",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.3"
  },
```

Example gastby-config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Free React Admin dashboard template based on Gatsby',
    description: 'Admin dashboard template based on Gatsby',
    author: 'Ahmed Elywa',
  },
  flags: {
    PRESERVE_FILE_DOWNLOAD_CACHE: true,
    PRESERVE_WEBPACK_CACHE: true,
    FAST_DEV: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-styled-components',
    'gatsby-plugin-typescript',
    'gatsby-plugin-antd',
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-layout`,
      options: {
        component: require.resolve(`./src/Layouts/index.tsx`),
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'images',
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        name: 'oah-admin',
        short_name: 'OAH',
        start_url: '/dashboard',
        display: 'minimal-ui',
        icon: 'src/images/OAH.png',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

and error shows when i import and use `button` comp componet
[image: my page]

can you give me some suggestions to fix this, thank you very much !

Comment: you completely changed the question, just ask a new one, id rollback but don't want to upset anyone

Comment: Hi there. Have you managed how to use Gatsby with antd?

Comment: @jupiteror Hi, Sorry for replying so late, I did it